# Jackson objectMapper gives different object for same json

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson, objectmapper

I'm passing a json to objectmapper. The JSON string looks like this:

```json
{          
  "id": "ID1",
  "identifier" : "XYZ",
  "data": [
  {
    "id": "sampleParentID",
    "childrenElements": [
    {
      "id" : "sampleChildID",
      "content" : "sample child content",  
    }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

```kotlin
 val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
 val obj: Object1 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString)
```

My class looks something like this :

```
data class Object 1 (
 var id : String? = null,
 var identifier : String? = null,
 var data: MutableList<Element>? = null,

){
 // some functions
}
```

```
class Element (
 var id : String?= null
 var content : String? = null
 var children: List<Element>? = listOf(),

) {
 // som functions
}
```

From obj, data field is nested which is an object itself.
I want to get hashCode of **data** so I do `obj.data.hashCode()`. Let's say 12345 gets generated.

I store this in the database. Now, let's say the user sends another request with exactly the same JSON, again the JSON gets converted into an object from which I extract the data field and now when I do `obj.data.hashCode()`, 12345 is not generated, rather some other number gets generated.

Is this behavior expected? If yes, what is the workaround?

**Update** : Added classes description.

Comment: Can you please add the classes of your model to which you are mapping the JSON? It really depends on how `hashCode()` was implemented.

Comment: Hey. Added the classes. Should I declare something differently?

Comment: Did you implement `hashCode()` for `Element`? If not, then each instance generates a different hash code, even if it has the same contents. Also, if you mean to identify objects using `hashCode()` then remember this value is not unique. Collisions are rare, but it is possible that objects with different contents have the same hash code.

Comment: And if you store many objects like this in the database, probability of collisions greatly increases due to [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: Right. I am not implementing my own `hashCode()` method. I think will have to write a custom `hashCode()` function. Thanks!

Comment: IntelliJ can generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` for you automatically. Or, if you can turn `Element` into data class, it will get it for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your `Element` class is not a data class (in this case you would get a `hashCode()` method implementation based on all class properties) you will need to write the `hashCode()` method yourself so that the default one (based on object memory reference) is not used and you get rid of the behaviour you are currently facing.